# Call function pointer at void* on object at void* OR Identify function so you will be able to compare the bindings

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm creating my own delegate implementation (I'm looking at C# delegates). I have an object-function binding struct

```
struct ObjFunc
{
    void* obj = nullptr;
    void* func = nullptr;

    ObjFunc(void* obj, void* func)
        : obj(obj)
        , func(func)
    {
    }
};
```

And I have a `Call` function

```
void Call(InTypes... args)
{
    auto bindings_copy = bindings_;

    for (auto& binding : bindings_copy)
    {
        try
        {
            if (binding.obj)
            {
                (binding.obj->*static_cast<void(T::*)(InTypes...)>(binding.func))(std::forward<InTypes>(args)...); // <- Problem Here
            }
            else
            {
                (*static_cast<void(*)(InTypes...)>(binding.func))(std::forward<InTypes>(args)...);
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            //print_warning("Delegate", "Bad delegate binding on %s object %p and function %p", typeid(binding.obj).name(), binding.obj, binding.func);
        }
    }
}
```

Before call I have to cast my function ptr to member function of some class, for example T, but I don't know which class will be used be at runtime

Or, at least, tell how to identify function in some generic manner, so I'll be able to ensure that pointer to some unknown function differs from another pointer to some unknown function

Comment: This code is not going to work. It would break on something as simple as being given a function pointer of the form `void(*)(int)` but calling it with an lvalue, because that would make `InTypes` be `int&`. You would cast your function pointer to a `void(*)(int&)`, which does not match the signature of the original `void(*)(int)` type, and thus yield UB. There's a reason why `std::function` takes the types of the parameters.

Comment: Plus casting a function pointer to a `void*` (or vice versa) is **undefined behavior**.  And member function pointers, which are different beasts than function pointers, probably wouldn't fit in a `void*` anyway.  (I did not downvote.  SO guidance to downvoters is to refrain from commenting, because it often leads to flamewars.)

Comment: First of all, great thank you for answers. Okay, my second approach is to store map of object-function binding (required for unbinding function from delegate) and std::function for simplier calls. In this case I don't need to call a function from void, but I still need to identify unknown function of unknown class just to check if they differ (as I may use void* for objects)

Comment: I'm already thinking about to memcpy data from function pointer inside templated function into byte array just to compare them

Comment: @Eljay: It's not UB; it's conditionally-supported. That is, implementations may allow it.

Comment: @Espeon: "*my second approach*" Approach to *what*? What is this code trying to do?

Comment: I think this code is trying to do C# style delegates.

Comment: To create a delegate. Like in C#. I want to store pointers to functions (with same signatures, of course) just to call them at once when I need and to be able to unbind them by specific object and specific function, this is why I need this object-function binding, for identifying

Comment: Yeah, memcpy seem to work. This is the result of my tests: https://imgur.com/a/XdWoq8d. I used a long long to store data, but it have a lot of unused butes, so it's better to perform memcpy into some char array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, even if it's impossible to call a function from pointer, second task (identify function in uniform format) still may be solved. You can use `memcpy` to copy data from function pointer. Example:

```
template<typename FSIG>
char* get_function_identifier(const FSIG& func_pointer, int& size)
{
    size = sizeof(FSIG);
    char* result = new char[size];
    memcpy(result, &func_pointer, size);
    return result;
}
```

This function returns you char buffer, containing identifying info about function

P.S. Note that this char array is not a c-style string! it does not have terminating character, so `strcmp` and all other C string operations shouldn't be applied

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to erase type from known type, something like:

```
struct ObjFunc
{
    template <typename T, typename Ret, typename C, typename ... Args>
    static call_mem(void* objPtr, void* funcPtr, Args... args)
    {
        T* obj = reinterpret_cast<T*>(objPtr);
        Ret (*func)(Args...) = reinterpret_cast<Ret (C::*)(Args...)>(funcPtr);
        (obj->*func)(args...);
    }
    template <typename T, typename Ret, typename C, typename ... Args>
    static call_const_mem(void* objPtr, void* funcPtr, Args... args)
    {
        T* obj = reinterpret_cast<T*>(objPtr);
        Ret (*func)(Args...) = reinterpret_cast<Ret (C::*)(Args...) const>(funcPtr);
        (obj->*func)(args...);
    }
    template <typename Ret, typename ... Args>
    static call_func(void* p, void* funcPtr, Args... args)
    {
        assert(p == nullptr);
        Ret (*func)(Args...) = reinterpret_cast<Ret (*)(Args...)>(funcPtr);
        func(args...);
    }

    void* obj = nullptr;
    void* func = nullptr;
    void* f = nullptr;

    template <typename T, typename Ret, typename C, typename ... Args>
    ObjFunc(T& obj, Ret (C::*func)(Args...) const)
        : obj(&obj)
        , func(func)
        , f(call_const_mem<T, ret, C, Args...>)
    {
    }
    template <typename T, typename Ret, typename C, typename ... Args>
    ObjFunc(T& obj, Ret (C::*func)(Args...))
        : obj(&obj)
        , func(func)
        , f(call_mem<T, ret, C, Args...>)
    {
    }
    template <typename T, typename Ret, typename C, typename ... Args>
    ObjFunc(Ret (*func)(Args...))
        : obj(nullptr)
        , func(func)
        , f(call_func<T, ret, C, Args...>)
    {
    }
    template <typename ...Ts>
    void Call(Ts... args) const
    {
        reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void*, void*, Ts...)>(f)(obj, func, args...);
    }
    
};
```

but simpler would be to use `std::function`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand about std::function, but it doesn't allow you to identify bounded function and object. This is why I added second part into question title, right after '|'. I wanted to implement unbinding functionality to my delegate. So I had two approaches: store list of object-function voids, what allows me to identify them both and successfully unbind the binding, but it is a pain with function calling. Second one is to use map with object-function as  key and std::function as value, but in both cases I need to identify function by something like void* at least

Comment: [`std::function::target`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) might interest you.

Comment: Actually, yes. I'll take a look at this tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: https://pastebin.com/B0ATnMRg - this is how my binding looks now + some part of class declaration. Now compiler says Error C2440 : 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,T *&,void (__cdecl ExampleMod::* &)(const std::weak_ptr<World> &)>' to 'std::function<void (const std::weak_ptr<World> &)>' on line 9